# Open local html file in Google Glass browser

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have an HTML file in my res/raw that I want to view in the Google glass browser.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773441/500681) suggests either copying to shared storage or using a WebView.

I cant seem to make the WebView scroll using the touchpad in the same way the browser does, which renders it useless for my purposes.

I tried copying the file to shared storage (i.e. /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/my.namespace/files/page.html) and using

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
```

but I get this exception:

```
03-18 17:58:53.338: E/AndroidRuntime(5315): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/my.namespace/files/page.html typ=text/html }
```

I've checked with adb shell and the file is at that location.  Any ideas why this may not be working? Is it a glass specific issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you have this error message: `"ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent"`, you need to define what activity must open your intent, in this case the browser.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

//you need define this activity to open your html file.
i.setClassName("com.google.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
//intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));

i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
```

**EDIT:**
The activity to start the browser in glass is:

```
i.setClassName("com.google.glass.browser", "com.google.glass.browser.WebBrowserActivity")
```

Comment: The stock android browser isn't available on Glass so I get `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}` after a bit of digging and decompiling of GlassBrowser.apk i've found the required activity is `i.setClassName("com.google.glass.browser", "com.google.glass.browser.WebBrowserActivity")`.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I suppsed that was the cause of the exception but hope tp work even more with google glass in the future.

Comment: Just to mention that if you want to open an online website, you can do
`intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));                     intent.setClassName("com.google.glass.browser", "com.google.glass.browser.WebBrowserActivity");`